# Combine two javascript Functions in one

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm a beginner with Angular and Javascript, I'm trying to refresh a dashboard.
so I use the first one to do the refresh and the second one to stop the refresh.
I want to combine these two functions to refresh and stop after a period of time.

```
    let refreshInterval;
    function refreshDataSource(){
      console.log("going to refresh ..")
      refreshInterval= setInterval(() => {
        console.log("refreshing ...");
        viz.refreshDataAsync();
      },3000);
    }

    function stopdata(){
      console.log("stop refresh ...");
      clearInterval(refreshInterval);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside the function `refreshDataAsync()` you can call `stopdata()` after you are done with your operations.

or you can also `await` the function `refreshDataAsync()` and then call `stopdata()` inside `refreshDataSource()`.

Comment: How I can use await ?

Comment: await refreshDataAsync()

Comment: try calling `stopdata()` inside `refreshDataAsync()` after updating UI with data.